# Efficient ways to compress/serialize/manipulate large amount of data

Tags: java, python, performance

I have a file with 25,000 floats (`,` delimited) and there are about 100K such rows. A row of the file looks something like:

```
1689.97,-9643.39,-82082.1,9776.09,-33974.84,-67247.38,32997.34,72811.53,31642.87,-949.6,9340.68,-85854.48,-17705.36,187.74,-3002.6,-35812.21,37382.32,22770.78,40893.09,45743.99,-6500.92,26243.85,13975.95,0,56669.47,-25865.36,-17066.78,26788.57,0,-36554.86,-3687.19,18933.93
```

I have a 2 part question.

1. Is there a way (in Java or Python) to compress data efficiently without effecting the performance much. The compression would be done once per day, but data has to be read quite often.
2. Can the data be manipulated in the compressed form e.g. I would like to aggregate first 10 columns on the first 10 rows without decompressing. That way I dont have to worry about frequent reads to compressed data. One of the challenges would be converting 25,000 string to float for addition.

I have looked at `gzip` and `zcat` and  they are good options. But I wanted to find some compression or serializing algo to store data through `Java/Python` and perform reads without decompressing.

Comment: Lookie: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/87679/advice-on-handling-large-data-volumes

Comment: The file must be an ASCII file, or you can consider having a binary file instead? The floats are single or double precision? If they are single precision then probably the easiest thing is to store the binary representation of the floats in the file.

Comment: To whoever reverted the changes to the question: 1) tags do not belong to the title and thus "in java" should *not* be mentioned there. There is a tag for that(and the OP is using it). Also, the formatting I gave is correct. The Op wanted an enumerand list and now it has it, and that huge line must definitely be displayed as code.

Comment: @David: thanks. I'll take a look at the mapped byte buffers.

Comment: @Bakuriu: I have thought of storing them as binary. the only problem is when I have to read, I'd have to deserialize. Was hoping there is a way to read it as binary and do manipulations, then convert it back to ascii

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Java, you can wrap your `OutputStream` with a [GZIPOutputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPOutputStream.html) and your `InputStream` with a [GZIPInputStream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/GZIPInputStream.html) to compress/decompress your data on the fly using the GZIP algo.

Answer (score 0):

use `DataOutPutStream` and writeFloat and you don't need use comma separator

Comment: This does not imply that the resulting file will be smaller. Floats can take up to 8 bytes to be represented, if the ASCII representation is smaller the file size might increase, or might be reduced by a small factor.

Comment: `DataOutputStream out = <br>new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("out.dat"));`<br> 
   `// out.writeFloat(0F); // 4bytes` <br> 
   `//out.writeChars("0,");  // 4 bytes` <br>
   `out.close();` <br> at worst, is the same size

Comment: No `0,` are *two* bytes, since it's ASCII. Also, if they are doubles then `12345.67` takes 8 bytes, which is the same as its binary representation. There is a quite high probability that the size would decrease but it depends on the representation of the floats in ASCII. Also, gzipping the ASCII file reduces its size by half, while a binary file would probably be compressed by a smaller amount(which, again doesn't guarantee that the binary representation in the end will be smaller).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing it out as text, you could write it out as bytes.  You would have to convert to/from premitives to byte arrays, but I don't think that would be too hard.  I know you can use [Float.floatToRawIntBits()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#floatToRawIntBits%28float%29) to convert to an int and [Float.intBytesToFloat()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#intBitsToFloat%28int%29) to go back from the int. Converting an int to a byte[] is just a matter of a couple of bit shifts.